# PyQT6 setWindowFlags issue

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

In my program i code a line
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.Tool)
Why python tell me
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.Tool)
NameError: name 'QtCore' is not defined

Comment: Probably because you didn't import QtCore, or you imported its contents directly. To use that line, you should've had `from PyQt5 import QtCore` at least.